# Can't find ON Restriction to do a full LEFT JOIN in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate

I am trying to make a hibernate query from a SQL query and I am struggling to do a full LEFT/RIGHT JOIN on hibernate that displays all the rows from one of the table.

Important to know:

**DAILY_INVENTORY**

```
 inventory_id (one to many)
 added 
 wasted 
 date
```

**INVENTORY**

```
 id
```

This is what I have so far..

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(DailyInventory.class, "dailyinventory");
        c.createAlias("inventory", "inventory", JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN);
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("dateAdded", date));
```

A working SQL query looks like this:

```
    SELECT INVENTORY.NAME,
       DAILY_INVENTORY.DATE,
       DAILY_INVENTORY.ADDED,
       DAILY_INVENTORY.WASTED
FROM   DAILY_INVENTORY
       RIGHT JOIN INVENTORY
              ON INVENTORY.ID = DAILY_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID
                 AND DAILY_INVENTORY.DATE = "2015-11-29"
WHERE  INVENTORY.REST_ID = 12
GROUP  BY INVENTORY.ID
```

For the SQL code above to work as a RIGHT JOIN (**Displays all rows from inventory**), I have to use

```
"AND DAILY_INVENTORY.DATE = "2015-11-29"
```

**on ON clause not WHERE**, and I am assuming Restriction.eq works as where, and that is why it is not showing the FULL ROWS of INVENTORY. How do I replicate the SQL "ON" statement as Hibernate Query? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding a few concepts in Hibernate.  There is no explicit `ON` in a Hibernate query, because the graph itself tell Hibernate how it should join two things together.  Also, your criteria query makes reference to a right join, but you discuss a left join in the text below.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SQL statement from tables are from inventory left join daily inventory. but the hibernate is just opposite way around, because criteria is daily inventory, it should do a right join to inventory instead.

Comment: made it to a right join to avoid confusion